# UITableView edit mode delete button is hiding in IPhone 4s

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Delete button is not fully visible in smaller resolutions.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
    }
}
```

Below is my screenshot

[image]

**Update 1**

Screenshot for tableview cell constraints

[image]

Comment: Does it work for you in bigger resolution ?

Comment: @Bucket thanks for reply, yes it is working in other resolutions

Comment: You can try to debug view hierarchy and figure it out what is wrong.

Comment: Have you checked constraints and size of cell?

Comment: Hey, check if your layout constraints fit for small devices. Are you using storyboard? If yes, try to change the view's perspective to "iPhone4s size" to double-check it.

Comment: show the code that creates the content of the cell, and its constraints..

Comment: I am using storyboard, build the design with constraints, everything is working except this

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae that's why we ask for more code and details.. how do we replicate the bug?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ check the screenshot for constraints

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae try to provide minimal example - implement just a sample code that has the same bug. If a newly created cell with the same constraints in an empty project does not manifest this behaviour, you will know that it is a side effect of something else.

Comment: It looks like your table view (not the cell) is not constrained to the width of the view. So your cells are “hanging” off the right hand edge of the screen. So when you swipe the cell it is only showing part of the delete button. You can confirm this by looking when you swipe. Does the red part of the button show immediately or does the text scroll for a bit before the red shows? The red should show immediately.

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks for reply, your assumption is correct, text is scrolling. Now I understand the problem. Thanks for the explanation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so from your comment your table view is not constrained to the view properly. So your cells are "hanging" off the right edge of the screen.

To fix this you should add constraints in your storyboard.

Select the table view and hit the **add constraints** button. Select the four edges and put 0 in the box.

Then hit "add constraints" this should fix the problem you are having.

The add constraints button is the one that looks like a Star Wars Tie Fighter in the bottom right corner of the Interface Builder screen...

[image]